# how to print (get) user_name using user id in codeigniter view page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to get user_name using user_id in my view.
Following is my mode:

// Model

```
class main_model extends CI_Model {             
    public function getOrders() {
        $this->db->where( 'real', 1 );      
        $this->db->ORDER_BY( 'id', 'DESC' );        
        $query = $this->db->get('orders',10);
        return $query->result();
    }


    public function getUsername($id) {
        $this->db->where( 'id', $id );      
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

// And my Controller goes here below:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('main_model');
    $data['orders'] = $this->main_model->getOrders();       
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

// Following is my View file.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-responsive" border="3">
            <tr>
                <th>OID</th>
                <th>user_id</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($orders as $order): ?>
            <tr> 
                <td> <?= $order->id;?> </td>
                <td> <?= $order->uid;?> </td>
                <td> ? </td> <!-- Want to get user name using uid. -->
            </tr>           
            <?php endforeach;   ?>

        </table>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I have got user_id from my order table, and user name is on my users table, thus I have to get it from there. Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get user name by single query.
Simple change on getOrders() function in main_model

```
class main_model extends CI_Model {             
    public function getOrders() {
        $this->db->select('orders.*,(select u.user_name from users as u where u.id = orders.uid) as user_name');
        $this->db->where('real', 1 );      
        $this->db->ORDER_BY( 'id', 'DESC' );        
        $query = $this->db->get('orders',10);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

---

```
<tr> 
   <td> <?= $order->id;?> </td>
   <td> <?= $order->uid;?> </td>
   <td> <?= $order->user_name;?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get your user id from `getOrders()` call, then loop through your orders to get your user.  Then from Your `getUsername()` function in the model returns a user object, so in the controller call it and store the variable:

```
$orders = $this->main_model->getOrders(); 
foreach($orders as $order) {
      $user = $this->main_model->getUsername($uid);       
      $order->username = $user->username;
}
$data['orders'] = $orders;
```

Now the username is in your orders array, just add `<td> <?= $order->username;?> </td>`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137431/discussion-on-answer-by-pacio-how-to-print-get-user-name-using-user-id-in-code).

Comment: Yes This time i got this: "  array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#32 (8) { ["id"]=> string(3) "102" ["fname"]=> string(6) "Mariam" ["lname"]=> string(6) "Danish" ["email"]=> string(26) "dr.mariam.danish@gmail.com... "

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like this: 
**MODEL**

```
public function getUsername($id) {
    $this->db->where( 'id', $id );      
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->row();
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<?php foreach($orders as $order): 
    $username = $this->main_model->getUsername($order->uid);
?>
   <tr> 
      <td> <?= $order->id; ?> </td>
      <td> <?= $order->uid; ?> </td>
      <td> <?= $username->user_name; ?> </td>
   </tr>           
<?php endforeach;   ?>
```

Comment: Hey @Keith Asilom, Thanks a lot, you made my day.  It worked for me. Just want to know that is it ok to call controller/model in view file?

Comment: Yes @SaleemJafar you may call model in view, not the best approach, but yes you may. If you could join the tables that would be better.